# Return a curried function, like in Haskell

Tags: ruby, currying

I want to be able to call a function this way:

```
func = ->(a, b) {
  if ...
    method1  # error - it requires 2 arguments when it's being called

    # it should be method1(a, b) 
    # but I don't want that redundancy here
  elsif ...
    method2  # error - it requires 2 arguments when it's being called
  elsif ...
    method3  # error - it requires 2 arguments when it's being called
  else ...
    method4  # error - it requires 2 arguments when it's being called
  end
}

param1 = ....
param2 = ....

func.call(param1, param2) # ok so far but error in the block above

def method1(var1, var2)
end

def method2(var1, var2)
end

def method3(var1, var2)
end

def method4(var1, var2)
end
```

But I don't want to repeat myself inside the block `func = ->(a, b) {` by adding 2 arguments to the functions. Those of you who know Haskell will understand what I mean.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the name of the method you want to call as a string-variable (or symbol); then use `send` to pass this variable along with the arguments.

An example:

```
def method_one(a, b)
  # something_one
end

def method_two(a, b)
  # something_two
end

def method_three(a, b) # the method you call       
  if condition_one
    method_name = "method_one"
  elsif condition_two
    method_name = "method_two"
  else
    # something else
  end

  send(method_name, a, b) if method_name
end
```

If `method_one` and `method_two` are public methods, I would recommend using `public_send` instead of `send` simply because it is more explicit which could potentially help others who read your code.

Answer (score 2):

From the Haskell wiki: "Currying is the process of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments into a function that takes just a single argument and returns another function if any arguments are still needed."

OP does not provide a single argument, but no arguments at all. Anyway, Ruby does have a `curry` method which results in a `proc`:

```
proc1 = ->(var1,var2){p var1+var2}.curry
proc2 = proc1[1] #same as proc2 = proc1.call(1)
proc2[2] # => 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking for clarification here since this isn't going to fit in a comment:

My understanding of currying:

`method_one(a, b)` takes two arguments. 
If you call it using `method_one(a)`, it should return a partial function which expects one argument, and applies the first to the second. Eg.

```
def multiply(a, b=nil)
  if b
    a*b 
  else
    Proc.new { |b| a*b }
  end
end
```

This allows you to do stuff like:

```
def multiply_by_three(b)
  multiply(3).call
end
```

So do you want to:

pass in `a` and `b` to `func` and get back a `Proc` acting on `a` and `b` or,

define your separate `methods` outside and apply it inside `func` without using the `method_name(a,b)` form?